# How to prevent multiple selections of the same value in a @Html.DropDownListFor in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dropdown, html.dropdownlistfor

I want restrict users from selecting already selected values in same dropdown. My Screen looks like this:

[image]

On each 'Add' click the Service type and Service Location will be added to a partial view. For this drop down I am using `@Html.DropdownListFor` for binding values from the database.

```
<div class="row mt-3" id="servicelocation">
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("ServiceTypeCollection"))
    {
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-12">
        <label> Service Type</label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.Id, null, new { @class = "md-form droplist service-type" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Id)
    </div>
```

}

And in [HttpGet]

```
 public ActionResult Register(string guid)
    {
          var db = new VendorManagementContext();
          var types = db.ServiceTypes.Select(x =>
                     new SelectListItem()
                     {
                         Text = x.Name.ToString(),
                         Value = x.Id.ToString()
                     }).ToList();

            model.serviceTypes=types;
    }
```

Can anyone suggest how I can restrict its selected values to be not displayed in the next dropdowns?

Editted

we are calling partial method like this

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetPartial()
        {
            try
            {
                var model = new ServiceTypePartial();
                ViewBag.Id = Utility.ServiceTypes();
                ViewBag.ZipCodeId = Utility.ZipCodes();
                return PartialView("_ServiceTypePartialView", model);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

and view its like

```
<div id="AddServices">
    @Html.CollectionEditorFor(m => m.ServiceTypeCollection, "Editors/_ServiceTypePartialView", "/Account/GetPartial",
       "Add service location", new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
 </div>
```

Comment: When you click ‘Add’, what is being called? An action method or an Ajax function? Could you please show that?

Comment: On click of add button we are calling partial view as action method... like this [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetPartial()
        {
            try
            {
                var model = new ServiceTypePartial();
                ViewBag.Id = Utility.ServiceTypes();
                ViewBag.ZipCodeId = Utility.ZipCodes();
                return PartialView("_ServiceTypePartialView", model);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }